# How to enforce user must scroll pdf within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pdf file within iframe. I want user to scroll must in pdf file before submitting the form. i am trying with this,

```
var position = $('#myIframe').contents().scrollTop();
```

But not working. Please help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are loading pdf in iframe? may you share some code sample of it  and html of form too;

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind making a static height for your iframe, I have a solution for you.

**HTML and CSS**
 1. Wrap your iframe in a `div` container
 2. set `heights` for both your container and iframe (`height` of container should be the `height` you want your frame to be seen and the iframe `height` should be large enough to show entire pdf.)
 3. set container div's `overflow` to `scroll`

Now you have a scrollable "iframe".

**Javscript**

1. Get container element. (`var containerEl = $("#container")[0];`)
2. Write a `scroll` function. Within the scroll function find if the total height of the element (`scrollHeight`) is less than or equal to how much has been scrolled (`scrollTop`) plus the inner height (`clientHeight`) of the 
   element. If it is, remove `disabled` property from `button`

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lruqj35e/2/). Made some changes to @mJunaidSalaat's jsfiddle.

Answer (score 5):

Well I've tried almost an hour on this, Researched it, finally coming to a conclusion that Unfortunately **this is not possible** using this method.

The PDF is usually not a DOM element, it's rendered by PDF reader software. Every browser has its own mechanism for rendering PDFs, there is no standard. In some cases, the PDF might be rendered by PDF.js; in those situations you might be able to detect scrolling. But Adobe Reader, Foxit, and some of the native PDF rendering don't provide that option.

I've also created a Github [issue](https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject/issues/58#event-603169061) for this. But no use.

Sorry. Please update me if you could find any thing or any workaround.

Comment: Sorry I have spent a lot of time. But unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lruqj35e/1/) for your solution. You can disable the submit button for user until user scroll on your iframe.

```
function getFrameTargetElement(objI) {
  var objFrame = objI.contentWindow;
  if (window.pageYOffset == undefined) {
    objFrame = (objFrame.document.documentElement) ? objFrame.document.documentElement : objFrame = document.body;
  }
  return objFrame;
}

$("#myIframe").ready(function() {
   var frame = getFrameTargetElement(document.getElementById("myIframe"));

   frame.onscroll = function(e) {
     $('.submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Please instead of html(This IS an iframe) i want pdf file.

Comment: <iframe src="lesson2.pdf" id="iframe1"></iframe> and comment this //$('#iframe1').contents().find('html').html("...");  then not working

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#myIframe").ready(function() {
  var frame = getFrameTargetElement(document.getElementById("myIframe"));

  frame.onscroll = function(e) {
    $('.submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```